# image filters in java and android

Tags: java, android, image-processing

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have learned a lot in java and I faced an obstacle in the programming for image filters.
I would like to know how can I make filter like this in android? (java)
What should I know to do like this?

Comment: there isn't any tutorial who's teaching how to add effects or filters so I came here to share with you the problem and to know you knowledge ..

Comment: Did you look at https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/?

Comment: I looked but I have a question , it tells that it recommend to use an "image editor" do they make it first in that program and then change it to a java code .. or it seems that I'm dreaming ?

Comment: I'v seen the image editing but I didn't find a way to make filters like instagram filters , can anyone help ?